# Fields should not accept spaces at start and end of input

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In one of my forms, all input fields are allowing only whitespace characters to be submitted. This is also true for whitespace characters at both ends of the input.

The form is set up in HTML and has angular validators.

I want to check that: if there are spaces at the beginning or end of the input AND if the input is only spaces.

Generic message to be shown: "Input Invalid"
The pattern I have made is : "/^\s|\s$/"

How do I use this in my .ts file?
Any intuition would also help.

Comment: Take a look at the following - https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validator for whiteSpace

```
    import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function whiteSpaceValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  const space = /^([ ]+)$/;
   const spaceStart = /^([ ]+)/
    const spaceEd = /([ ]+$)/
  if (space.test(control.value) || spaceStart.test(control.value) || spaceEd.test(control.value)) {
    return { whiteSpace: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Add this validator on form

```
 this.discountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, whiteSpaceValidator]]
    });
```

Comment: I don't think the code fulfils the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is bunch of good writings to perform this task. Give this block a try it might work for you.

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
  
export class UsernameValidator {
    static cannotContainSpace(control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null {
        if((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') >= 0){
            return {cannotContainSpace: true}
        }
  
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code snippet is from 'https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-form-validation-no-whitespace-allowed-exampleexample.html'

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

To check for the spaces at the beginning and end of the string, there is a String method in javascript which removes the spaces at the beginning and end of the string.

For example:
var msg = " helloWorld " //Let us assume this is the input the user has provided which has spaces at the beginning and end of the string.

msg = msg.trim() // this statement will remove the spaces at beginning and end of the string and produces the output as "helloworld"

So now in your custom validator function use the **trim** method on the input field.